How to get Clickhouse distributed table to use Constraints on sharded tables for query optimization
I've got a distributed table events [1] and a bunch of sharded_events [2] tables. On the sharded_events tables, I've created a materialized column of some extracted out JSON and then added constraints so that the query optimizer knows to use it based on some ideas from https://posthog.com/blog/clickhouse-materialized-columns.
ALTER TABLE sharded_events on cluster posthog 
ALTER COLUMN materialized_$host_2 
TYPE VARCHAR DEFAULT JSONExtractString(properties, '$host');


ALTER table sharded_events on cluster posthog 
MATERIALIZE column materialized_$host_2;


alter table sharded_events on cluster posthog 
alter column materialized_$host_2 
type varchar materialized JSONExtractString(properties, '$host');


ALTER TABLE sharded_events on CLUSTER posthog 
ADD CONSTRAINT host_2_constraint 
ASSUME JSONExtractString(properties, '$host') = materialized_$host_2

After doing that, I'm seeing a big performance improvement on queries to the sharded_events tables that would otherwise have been doing a lot of JSONExtractStrings.
For example,
select count(*) from sharded_events 
where JSONExtractString(properties, '$host') like '%-ca%' 
limit 1 format Vertical 
SETTINGS use_query_cache = 0, optimize_using_constraints =1, 
optimize_substitute_columns = 1, convert_query_to_cnf =1, optimize_append_index=1;

takes less than 0.1 seconds, while
select count(*) from sharded_events 
where JSONExtractString(properties, '$host') like '%-ca%' 
limit 1 format Vertical 
SETTINGS use_query_cache = 0;

takes > 2 seconds.
The problem I've still got is I can't figure out how to add a constraint to the distributed events table like I've added to the sharded_events tables (like host_2_constraint above). Without adding that constraint, queries to the events table that could be using the materialized view remain un-optimized.
select count(*) from events 
where JSONExtractString(properties, '$host') like '%-ca%' 
limit 1 format Vertical 
SETTINGS use_query_cache = 0, optimize_using_constraints =1, 
optimize_substitute_columns = 1, convert_query_to_cnf =1, optimize_append_index=1;

takes >2 seconds whereas
select count(*) from events 
where materialized_$host_2 like '%-ca%' 
limit 1 format Vertical 
SETTINGS use_query_cache = 0, optimize_using_constraints =1, 
optimize_substitute_columns = 1, convert_query_to_cnf =1, optimize_append_index=1;

is < 0.1 seconds.
When I try to add a constraint on the events table, like
ALTER TABLE events on CLUSTER posthog 
ADD CONSTRAINT host_2_constraint 
ASSUME JSONExtractString(properties, '$host') = materialized_$host_2

I get the exception
DB::Exception: Alter of type 'ADD_CONSTRAINT' is not supported by storage Distributed. (NOT_IMPLEMENTED) (version 23.12.5.81 (official build)). (NOT_IMPLEMENTED)

So the question is, how can I add the constraint to the distributed table so that queries to the events table use the materialized view? Or is there another way to take advantage of the materialized view like I can when querying the sharded_events table?
[1] events
:) show table events

SHOW CREATE TABLE events

│ CREATE TABLE posthog.events
(
    `uuid` UUID,
    `event` String,
    ...
    ...
    ...

    `materialized_$host_2` String MATERIALIZED JSONExtractString(properties, '$host')
)
ENGINE = Distributed('posthog', 'posthog', 'sharded_events', sipHash64(distinct_id)) │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

1 row in set. Elapsed: 0.001 sec.


[2] sharded_events
:) show table sharded_events

SHOW CREATE TABLE sharded_events

│ CREATE TABLE posthog.sharded_events
(
    `uuid` UUID,
     ...
     ...
     ...
    `materialized_$host_2` String MATERIALIZED JSONExtractString(properties, '$host'),
,
    ...
    ...
    ...
    CONSTRAINT host_2_constraint ASSUME JSONExtractString(properties, '$host') = `materialized_$host_2`
)
ENGINE = ReplicatedReplacingMergeTree('/clickhouse/tables/{shard}/posthog.events', '{replica}', _timestamp)


distributed tables doesn't contains data, this is a proxy tables to allow distributed queries to underlying tables from engine=Distributed definition
better add SELECT ... FROM events SETTINGS use_query_cache = 0, optimize_using_constraints =1,  optimize_substitute_columns = 1, convert_query_to_cnf =1, optimize_append_index=1;
and use <secret> in <remote_servers> config section to allow to initialize security context as initial user, not as default

Thanks for the response @Slach! I'm aware that the distributed table doesn't actually store data, just uses the underlying sharded_events tables, but I don't understand from https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/operations/server-configuration-parameters/settings#server-settings-remote-servers or https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/engines/table-engines/special/distributed how setting  would affect the query optimizer knowing to use the constraints on the distributed tables when the events table is queried. Or was that good, but unrelated, advice? Either way, thanks!

 allow pass  settings with initial user security context
according to https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/create/table#constraint
looks like if you insert data into distributed table it will infinite insert to underlying table
I think you can apply SETTINGS distributed_foreground_insert=1 for your insert to get exception if constrains fail

Both before and after setting  the user and initial_user are the same in the query log and the settings in the query log are the same.
If I run the query that was sent to the shard directly on the shard with the same user, it is optimized. I wonder if optimizations aren't being applied for some reason on non-initial queries? Could this be related to https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/pull/28746/files ?
